# Friend funcitons of template classes

Tags: c++, templates

I want to return a nested class object using a friend function

```
template <typename T>
class X{
public:
    class Y{
    public:
        int y;
    }test;
public:
    X(){
        test.y=10;
    }

    template <typename U>
    friend Y fun(X<U>);
};


template <typename T>
X<T>::Y fun(X<T> x){
    return x.test;
}
```

But I get an error saying

need 'typename' before 'X::Y' because 'X' is a dependent scope

What is wrong?

Comment: `need 'typename' before 'X::Y' because 'X' is a dependent scope` You need `typename` before `X::Y`.

Comment: Because `X` is a dependent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do literally what the error says: put `typename` before `X<T>::Y`:

```
template <typename T>
typename X<T>::Y fun(X<T> x){
    return x.test;
}
```

Because the meaning of `X<T>::Y` is type-dependent on `T`, the compiler can't know in general whether `X<T>::Y` refers to a typename or a variable. In such circumstances the rule is that if you want it to be typename, you must say so explicitly with the `typename` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
template <typename T>
typename X<T>::Y fun(X<T> x){
    return x.test;
}
```

becouse compliler can't resolve if `Y` is filed or type.